# how to pass querystring in friendly url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following action. I can hit this with

/basket/address?addressId=123

However i wonder how i can hit it with

/basket/address/123

```
 public ActionResult Address(int addressId)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

my  routes

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",                      // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults

       );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
public ActionResult Address(int addressId)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Address(int id)
```